# regular expression which checks that a string is between 8-15 characters

Tags: regex

Does any know how to write a regular expression which checks that a string is between 8-15  characters long. It does not matter what those character are. No line breaks are allowed.

I am looking for a regular expression to validate my user's password. My users are allowed to enter a password between 8-15 characters long and it could be either alphamumeric or nonalphanumberic character.  I hope this is clear.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why use regular expressions for this? Just use string methods to get the length and compare it. E.g. in Python `if 8 <= len(str) <= 15:`

Comment: @FelixKling Because Regexes are the new jQuery :-) Or is jQuery the new Regexes? :-) :-)

Comment: @xanatos: jQuerex :) .. or Regquery ...

Comment: I am using asp.net and would like to validate on the client side

Answer (score 2):

```
^[\s\S]{8,15}$
```

I'm not using the `.` as "any character" because often it's in reality "any character but newline". `[\s\S]` means any space or any non space (so anything).

Now. Please. Remeber the first rule of Regexes: **You do not talk about Regexes!!!** (I hope you've see Fight Club)

Answer (score 1):

`^.{8,15}$` in most regex dialects.

Comment: Small correction. Minimum 8 characters. And you should add ^ and $ to anchor it. Otherwise a 16 long string will be captured as a 15 long substring

Comment: I'll add that at this point I've already showed that it's impossible to write a correct Regex in a single try. :-)

Comment: Or `\A` and `\z` if you're on Ruby. And you might need to set the DOTALL option if you have one. Otherwise, you need something like `[\S\s]` instead of `.`. Moral: When asking regex questions, always include the regex flavor you're planning on using.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest if you really mean *any* character would be 
^.{8,15}$

Comment: As written by the OP, and considering that quite often the `.` doesn't match new line (that is a valid character in a string), this is wrong :-) :-) `^[\s\S]{8.15}$`

Comment: @xanatos: Har har har. You've just proven with your own regex that it's impossible to write a correct regex on the first try.

Comment: haha, yes, you never do get a regex right first time :)  I'm assuming they don't mean _any_ character though.

Comment: @GaryBarker: Definitely not. This misses out on (depending on the language you're using) over 99 % of possible characters.

Comment: But you can use [\w\W] or [\d\D] probably :-)

Comment: I was struggling to think in what circumstances you would want to match a string of 8 - 15 characters that can include **any** character?  And since netNewBee was a new signup I thought perhaps their definition of character was different to yours as someone who would be quite specific when dealing with regexes :)

Comment: Thanks for all your input.  I am looking for a regular expression to validate my user's password.  My users are allowed to enter a password between 8-15 characters long and it could be either alphamumeric or nonalphanumberic character.  Does that make more sense now?